# How to split data in different workbooks in different sheets using Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I want to split the data which is present in the master workbook into different workbooks according to the product code present in the master workbook like `A01,A02,B01,B02,C01,C02` the data related to the codes should be saved in the new workbook with sheets name as per the product name. please help me with the coding. the image shows the master workbook.

Comment: How to do this is documented here. The common route (from what I have seen) is to determine your unique list of product codes. Loop through that list and filter your master workbook, copy the visible cells to a NEW SHEET and rename sheet to match your product. Then, another macro to loop through your book saving all sheets as their own workbook. Each step above is documented on this site (and others). Try to stitch them all together :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a pretty good tool to split a workbook into several different workbooks based on the values in a column, see

https://www.howtoexcel.org/vba/how-to-export-your-data-into-separate-workbooks-based-on-the-values-in-a-column/

It should be fairly easy to adapt this to produce workbooks with the sheet names as you want them.

Hope this helps.